# Simple-Auth: Trouble getting started

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I am having trouble following [SimpLabs' starting guide for ember-simple-auth](http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/).

Following the guides on the home page, word for word, does not work.

When I test my login form, the "authenticate" action goes up to the controller and errors.

---

**Stack:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticate' of undefined
    at http://local-03-02-xx.lariatcentral.net/assets/vendor.js:61403:48
    at invokeResolver (http://local-03-02-xx.lariatcentral.net/assets/vendor.js:23342:9)
    at new Promise (http://local-03-02-xx.lariatcentral.net/assets/vendor.js:23328:9)
    at __exports__.default.Ember.ObjectProxy.extend.authenticate (http://local-03-02-xx.lariatcentral.net/assets/vendor.js:61402:16)
    at __exports__.default.Ember.Mixin.create.actions.authenticate (http://local-03-02-xx.lariatcentral.net/assets/vendor.js:61176:62)
    at apply (http://local-03-02-xx.lariatcentral.net/assets/vendor.js:21143:27)
    at superFunction [as _super] (http://local-03-02-xx.lariatcentral.net/assets/vendor.js:17841:15)
    at __exports__.default.Ember.Mixin.create.actions.authenticate (http://local-03-02-xx.lariatcentral.net/assets/vendor.js:61234:23)
    at apply (http://local-03-02-xx.lariatcentral.net/assets/vendor.js:21141:32)
    at superWrapper (http://local-03-02-xx.lariatcentral.net/assets/vendor.js:20721:15)
```

---

**Code**

*app/routes/application.js*

```
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin);
```

*app/controller/login.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import LoginControllerMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/login-controller-mixin';

export default Ember.Controller.extend(LoginControllerMixin, {
    authenticator: 'authenticator:custom'
});
```

*app/templates/login.hbs*

```
<form {{action authenticate on='submit'}}>
    <div>
        <label for="identification">
            <span class="sr-only">Login:</span>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                {{input type="text" value=identification id="identification" class="form-control" placeholder="Login"}}
             </div>
         </label>
     </div>
     <div>
         <label for="password">
             <span class="sr-only">Password:</span>
             <div class="input-group">
                 <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                 {{input type="password" value=password id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"}}
             </div>
         </label>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block action-sm">Login</button>
 </form>
```

---

Is there an extra step that the website forgot to mention?  I feel like I have checked and rechecked everything...

Comment: Can you find out where the error actually comes from? The provided stack trace doesn't really help as that's from your vendor.js.

Comment: @marcoow I mad a little forward progress last night, but still having some issues.  I will edit my post when I figure out what changed.